# Is it possible to build a dynamic list of targets with Earthly

Tags: build, earthly

I've been considering the [Earthly](https://docs.earthly.dev/) build automation tool as a replacement for Make in my project. I have a mono repo with a root Makefile, that has a target that scans for subfolders with Makefiles, and builds those with `make -C some_subfolder`.

Looking at the documentation for Eartly, the only way I can see to support those builds is to make a static lists of subfolders, and then build them using the example from the [mono repo documentation](https://docs.earthly.dev/examples/other-earthfile-examples/monorepo), like

```
FROM alpine:3.13

all:
    BUILD ./some_subfolder+all
    BUILD ./another_folder+all
```

I've been through the rest of the guides, and I can't see any way to make that list of build instructions dynamic, without writing a wrapper script to run Earthly. Has anyone else had this issue and come up with a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent versions of Earthly you can use the new [`FOR` command](https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/earthfile#for-experimental).

```
VERSION 0.6

build:
  ...
  FOR dir IN $(ls -d */)
    BUILD "./$dir+build"
  END
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually noticed by complete coincidence about a week ago, but thanks for remembering my issue and posting back!

Comment: The new syntax is better than the solution I wound up with then https://github.com/earthly/earthly/issues/920#issuecomment-816984853 